# How to extract numbers from string using a pattern?

Tags: python, string, pandas, design-patterns, extract

I have the following ten rows in a pandas dataframe. I want to extract the coordinates as in [49,49],[31,78] etc.(for each row).

I tried to use string extract but I couldn't figure out the pattern.

This is what I tried. I am not sure I understand how this works though:

b is the dataframe and positions is the column

```
b.positions.str.extract("""[{'y': (\d+), 'x': (\d+)}],""")

[{'y': 49, 'x': 49}, {'y': 78, 'x': 31}]
[{'y': 78, 'x': 31}, {'y': 75, 'x': 51}]
[{'y': 75, 'x': 51}, {'y': 71, 'x': 35}]
[{'y': 71, 'x': 35}, {'y': 95, 'x': 41}]
[{'y': 95, 'x': 41}, {'y': 88, 'x': 72}]
[{'y': 88, 'x': 72}, {'y': 75, 'x': 77}]
[{'y': 25, 'x': 23}, {'y': 15, 'x': 39}]
[{'y': 15, 'x': 39}, {'y': 20, 'x': 33}]
[{'y': 85, 'x': 61}, {'y': 80, 'x': 67}]
[{'y': 80, 'x': 67}, {'y': 61, 'x': 59}]
[{'y': 61, 'x': 59}, {'y': 45, 'x': 45}]
```

Comment: Is your column a string or actually of type list with 2 dictionaries in each?

Comment: how about `df['col'].apply(lambda x: [i.values() for i in x])`

Comment: Well I am using spyder and via the variable explorer I selected the whole column and with a right click -> to str, I suppose that it was converted to string

Comment: "I tried to use string extract" - may we see your code, edited into the question? Thanks!

Comment: @anky_91 I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *str.extractall* and named capturing groups.
Assuming that the source column holding your strings is named *col1*, the code is:

```
df.col1.str.extractall(r"'y': (?P<y>\d+), 'x': (?P<x>\d+)")
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
           y   x
   match        
0  0      49  49
   1      78  31
1  0      78  31
   1      75  51
2  0      75  51
   1      71  35
3  0      71  35
   1      95  41
4  0      95  41
   1      88  72
5  0      88  72
   1      75  77
6  0      25  23
   1      15  39
7  0      15  39
   1      20  33
8  0      85  61
   1      80  67
9  0      80  67
   1      61  59
10 0      61  59
   1      45  45
```

The first level in the MultiIndex of the result (unnamed) is the
index from the source row.
The second level (named *match*) is the match number for the current row,
starting from *0*.

Comment: Thank you. This is excellent!